# Can't release componentsSeparetedByString array

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

I have a simple method run in background thread which open txt file and split it on lines. After that I'm trying to release memory, but something goes wrong. I'm using ARC. Here's code:

```
@autoreleasepool {
   NSString* file = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:resourcePath encoding:NSWindowsCP1251StringEncoding error:&error];
   NSArray* test = [file componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
   test = nil;
 }
```

String released fine, but array still in memory. What I've missed?

**UPD:** Hm... Just tried to duplicate array few times, and after end of the method array really deallocates. But there is memory leak if I create this array. Where it could be?

Comment: Where are you testing if the array has been released?

Comment: array hasn't been release, and this is the main problem, txt file is 37 megabytes and after this code app using 100 megabytes of ram

Comment: You didn't answer my question. How do you know it wasn't released?

Comment: if i comment out array initialization, app using only 18 megabytes of ram, just looking in activity monitor

Comment: i think these data stay in dirty memory, and it will released when it be neccessary

Comment: The array is released when the `@autoreleasepool` ends.

Answer (score 0):

```
   // test = nil;
```

Dismiss it, and ARC will work fine.